# Flushing Twisted's write buffer

Tags: python, tcp, buffer, twisted

Twisted's `Connection` class inherits the `write` method from the abstract class `FileDescriptor`. As you can see [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.0.0/twisted/internet/abstract.py#L174), the class has a buffer which is not flushed until the total number of buffered bytes is greater than `bufferSize` (attribute in class `FileDescriptor`).

For my specific needs, I'd like to write data to the socket as soon as possible, so I would like to avoid buffering them at any point of the transmission. I have set `TCP_NODELAY` to the socket but data is still buffered at Twisted's `write` call.

So, my approach to tackle this is to call `FileDescriptor.doWrite` method, which will try to write any data in the buffer (see [source](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.0.0/twisted/internet/abstract.py#L90)). I call `doWrite` always after `write` as follows:

```
...
self.transport.write(data)
self.transport.doWrite()
...
```

The workaround seems to be working fine but, from time to time, the following bug comes to the surface:

```
    self.transport.doWrite()  # Flush twisted buffer
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-14.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 270, in doWrite
    self.stopWriting()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-14.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 429, in stopWriting
    self.reactor.removeWriter(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-14.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 344, in removeWriter
    EPOLLOUT, EPOLLIN)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-14.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 322, in _remove
   primary.remove(fd)
KeyError: 11
```

The problem is that `doWrite` calls `stopWriting`, which attempts to [remove](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.0.0/twisted/internet/abstract.py#L257) itself (the `Connection` object) from the writers list in the `reactor`. The exception raises because it cannot find this object in the list.

It's strange because `write` should register the reader in case the `data` argument is not `None` (I thought the problem was that data sometimes was `None`, so I included `write` & `doWrite` under the condition of data being present). So, I decided to just catch the `KeyError` exception and ignore it as follows:

```
...
if data:
    self.transport.write(data)
    try:
        self.transport.doWrite()
    except KeyError:
        pass
...
```

Yet, the exception keeps popping and even closes the TCP connection.

I don't know where and why the exception is raised now that I catch it in `doWrite`. Also, I don't know what are the side-effects of this hack. It might be that I'm oversimplifying the whole Twisted's file descriptor paradigm (I don't understand it enough yet). I also don't know if this is the actual expected behaviour, **shouldn't Twisted check whether the element is in the list of writers before removing it from the list in any case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doWrite` isn't there for you to call.  It is part of the interface between the transport and the reactor.  It is not part of the interface between the transport and the protocol.

`FileDescriptor` does not buffer writes until a certain number of bytes have been written.  It only buffers writes (at most) until the reactor gets a chance to run again.  Twisted is a cooperative multi-tasking system.  Only one thing happens at a time.  If the one thing that's happening is your application code running then the reactor isn't taking care of its job (like writing bytes to file descriptors).  Each thing has to wait for the other to finish before it can start.

Whatever led you to the conclusion that there's a size-based write buffer was a mistake.  Whatever problem you're trying to solve, the solution doesn't look like this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I see that chunks of data passed as arguments to different `write` calls are combined together in a single TCP segment, even though I have disabled Nagle's algorithm using   the transport method `setTcpNodDelay()`. It is true that I see this happening after a certain amount of bytes has been written (btw, do you know how do you choose that threshold?).  My goal is to force Twisted to send those chunks in different segments, even though the reactor cannot write as soon as it arrives because it's busy handling other events. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You can't. Even if you can force Twisted to issue separate `send` calls (which would be tricky), your operating system or any intermediary router is at liberty to coalesce the segments together.  The reason to disable Nagle is for performance reasons, not to try to turn TCP into a message-oriented protocol: it isn't one, it's a stream-oriented protocol.

Comment: @Glyph: Thanks for your comment. I'm doing that for a very specific purpose (as I said , it's for a research project), the packets are going to be sent over the loopback interface and will die there. So, I would be interested in using different `send` calls. Should I use `send` instead of `write`?

Comment: You might want to register your code as a producer for the transport http://twisted.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core/howto/producers.html and only do one write at a time, waiting for `resumeProducing`, so you only write data while the write buffer is empty.

Comment: @Glyph: okay, thanks. So, as far as I understand, I'll need to probe the write buffer in the implementation of `resumeProducing` of my own producer. I send stuff while the buffer is empty, otherwise, I pause the producer, right? But, is the producer resumed when the protocol receives new data? I would like to resume it as soon as the buffer is flushed... One last question, what would you recommend to check whether the buffer is empty or not? Thank you. (I'm basing this comment on this example: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/streaming.py)

Comment: Oh, now I see. `doWrite` will call `resumeProducing` when the buffer becomes empty. So, can I have multiple producers and produce asynchronously, right? (In the example above, they use a blocking loop)

Comment: @Glyph: now I only write when producer is resumed (that is when write buffer is empty), but I still see that packets are coalesced. Is there any other buffer in Twisted that I'm missing? Interestingly, with the approach described in my question, the coalesced packets reduced significantly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there are any buffers beyond the write buffer.  As I said before, *you can't do this*, your kernel is under no obligation to keep those packets un-coalesced, libc could be doing something weird, maybe even python's socket module (but I doubt it).  TCP is a stream of bytes and not a packet-oriented protocol, and if you manage to accidentally get it to send discrete packets in one situation, a tiny change to configuration might upset that the next time you run it so that it doesn't any more.